# Having an error with python and can't figure it out : TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, typeerror

line 28, in calculateSalesTax
    salesTax = totalPrices * 0.07;
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

```
def calculateSalesTax(salesTax, totalPrices):
    salesTax = totalPrices * 0.07;
    return salesTax, totalPrices;
```

totalPrices is the sum of many prices:

```
def getPrices(price1, price2, price3, price4, price5):
    price1 = float(input("<ENTER THE PRICECE FOR ITEM # 01> "));
    price2 = float(input("<ENTER THE PRICE FOR ITEM # 02> "));
    price3 = float(input("<ENTER THE PRICE FOR ITEM # 03> "));
    price4 = float(input("<ENTER THE PRICE FOR ITEM # 04> "));
    price5 = float(input("<ENTER THE PRICE FOR ITEM # 05> "));
    return price1, price2, price3, price4, price5;

def calculateTotalPrices(totalPrices, price1, price2, price3, price4, price5):
    totalPrices =(price1 + price2 + price3 + price4 + price5);
    return totalPrices, price1, price2, price3, price4, price5;
```

I am new with python and it gives me this error please help me.

Comment: `totalPrices` is a list, not a number. What are you expecting `totalPrices * 0.07` to be?

Comment: Why does `calculateSalesTax` take `salesTax` as a parameter if it's immediately reassigning the variable?

Comment: Please show how you're calling `calculateSalesTax`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you meant

```
>>> prices=(1.35, 34.57, 49.89)
>>> taxes = [p * 0.07 for p in prices]
>>> taxes
[0.094500000000000015, 2.4199000000000002, 3.4923000000000002]
```